# Improve a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I retrieved a project which takes a long time to run because of a SQL query.

I'd like to know if you know a way to improve it.
At least if there is a way to improve it.

From what I know, the query gets back 1500 lines and makes a SUM and COUNT from other tables.

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.datecreate,
p.title,
p.address,
p.address2,
p.code_postal,
p.ville,
p.description,
p.description_admin,
p.idstatut,
p.idstatut_admin,
p.reference,
p.star,
p.logo,
p.deleted,
cc.value as starcolor,
p.idsociete,
soc.nom as societe_nom,
s.titlestatut,
s.fontcolor,
s.label as label,
sa.titlestatut as titlestatut_admin,
sa.fontcolor as fontcolor_admin,
sa.label as label_admin,
(SELECT SUM(nbr) FROM plans as cplans WHERE cplans.idprojets = p.id) as count_commandes,
(SELECT count(id) FROM files as cfiles WHERE cfiles.idprojets = p.id AND cfiles.folder = '1' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '0') as count_averifier,
(SELECT count(rowid) FROM files_modif_title as cfmt WHERE cfmt.idprojets = p.id AND cfmt.statut = '7' AND cfmt.hide = '0') as count_modif_nohide,
(SELECT count(rowid) FROM files_modif_title as cfmt WHERE cfmt.idprojets = p.id AND cfmt.statut = '7' AND cfmt.hide IN (1)) as count_modif_hide,
(SELECT count(id) FROM files as cfiles WHERE cfiles.idprojets = p.id AND cfiles.folder = '2' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '0') as count_bat_attente,
(SELECT count(id) FROM files as cfiles WHERE cfiles.idprojets = p.id AND cfiles.folder = '2' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '1') as count_bat_valider
FROM projets as p INNER JOIN societe AS soc ON p.idsociete = soc.id
INNER JOIN statuts AS s ON p.idstatut = s.id
INNER JOIN statuts AS sa ON p.idstatut_admin = sa.id
LEFT JOIN const AS cc ON cc.name = p.star AND cc.parent = 'star'
WHERE  p.idstatut IN (3)
AND p.deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.datecreate DESC
```

Thank you guys !

Edit -----

Here what I did, could it be better ?

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.datecreate,
    p.title,
    p.address,
    p.address2,
    p.code_postal,
    p.ville,
    p.description,
    p.description_admin,
    p.idstatut,
    p.idstatut_admin,
    p.reference,
    p.star,
    p.logo,
    p.deleted,
    cc.value as starcolor,
    p.idsociete,
    soc.nom as societe_nom,
    s.titlestatut,
    s.fontcolor,
    s.label as label,
    sa.titlestatut as titlestatut_admin,
    sa.fontcolor as fontcolor_admin,
    sa.label as label_admin,
    CC.count_commandes,
    CA.count_averifier,
    CMN.count_modif_nohide,
    CMH.count_modif_hide,
    CBA.count_bat_attente,
    CBV.count_bat_valider
FROM
    projets as p
        INNER JOIN societe AS soc
            ON p.idsociete = soc.id
        INNER JOIN statuts AS s
            ON p.idstatut = s.id
        INNER JOIN statuts AS sa
            ON p.idstatut_admin = sa.id
        LEFT JOIN const AS cc
            ON cc.name = p.star
            AND cc.parent = 'star'
        LEFT JOIN (

                SELECT idprojets, SUM(nbr) as count_commandes
                FROM plans
                GROUP BY idprojets
            ) AS CC
            ON p.id = CC.idprojets
        LEFT JOIN (

                SELECT idprojets, COUNT(*) AS count_averifier
                FROM files
                GROUP BY idprojets
                WHERE cfiles.folder = 1 AND cfiles.bat_valid = 0
            ) AS CA
            ON p.id = CA.idprojets
        LEFT JOIN (

                SELECT idprojets, COUNT(*) as count_modif_nohide
                FROM files_modif_title
                WHERE statut = 7 AND hide = 0
                GROUP BY idprojets
            ) AS CMN
            ON p.id = CMN.idprojets
        LEFT JOIN (

                SELECT idprojets, COUNT(*) as count_modif_hide
                FROM files_modif_title
                WHERE statut = 7 AND hide = 1
                GROUP BY idprojets
            ) AS CMH
            ON p.id = CMH.idprojets
        LEFT JOIN (

                SELECT idprojets, COUNT(*)
                FROM files
                WHERE folder = 2 AND bat_valid = 0
                GROUP BY idprojets
            ) AS CBA
            ON p.id = CBA.idprojets
        LEFT JOIN (

                SELECT idprojets, COUNT(*)
                FROM files
                WHERE folder = 2 AND bat_valid = 1
                GROUP BY idprojets
            ) AS CBV
            ON p.id = CBV.idprojets
WHERE
    p.idstatut IN (3)
    AND p.deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.datecreate DESC;
```

Thanks to what you said, the main problem was the 6 SELECT are embedded in the SELECT clause. These are evaluated for each record put together by the application so it executes 1500 x 6 = 9000 queries! 
By doing this I had 9001 queries and now only 7 since subqueries are evaluated only once at runtime. Is that correct ?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: This looks fine. You'll want to ensure you have the correct indexes available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part you defiantly want to improve:

```
(SELECT SUM(nbr) FROM plans as cplans WHERE cplans.idprojets = p.id) as count_commandes,
(SELECT count(id) FROM files as cfiles WHERE cfiles.idprojets = p.id AND cfiles.folder = '1' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '0') as count_averifier,
(SELECT count(rowid) FROM files_modif_title as cfmt WHERE cfmt.idprojets = p.id AND cfmt.statut = '7' AND cfmt.hide = '0') as count_modif_nohide,
(SELECT count(rowid) FROM files_modif_title as cfmt WHERE cfmt.idprojets = p.id AND cfmt.statut = '7' AND cfmt.hide IN (1)) as count_modif_hide,
(SELECT count(id) FROM files as cfiles WHERE cfiles.idprojets = p.id AND cfiles.folder = '2' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '0') as count_bat_attente,
(SELECT count(id) FROM files as cfiles WHERE cfiles.idprojets = p.id AND cfiles.folder = '2' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '1') as count_bat_valider
```

You can use conditional aggregation for this and join the tables only once:

```
count(nbr) as..,
count(CASE WHEN cfiles.folder = '1' and cfiles.bat_valid = '0' then id END) as ..,
count(CASE WHEN cfiles.folder = '2' and cfiles.bat_valid = '0' then id END) as ..,
count(CASE WHEN cfiles.folder = '2' and cfiles.bat_valid = '1' then id END) as ..,
........
```

Add the joins

```
JOIN files cfiles
 ON(cfiles.idprojets = p.id)
```

Do exactly the same for `files_modif_title`

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice way to improve it ! I earn 80 % time at runtime :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Hopefully your main table has indexing
2. Instead of using sub-query, use join

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to create a new version !

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.datecreate,
p.title,
p.address,
p.address2,
p.code_postal,
p.ville,
p.description,
p.description_admin,
p.idstatut,
p.idstatut_admin,
p.reference,
p.star,
p.logo,
p.deleted,
cc.value as starcolor,
p.idsociete,
soc.nom as societe_nom,
s.titlestatut,
s.fontcolor,
s.label as label,
sa.titlestatut as titlestatut_admin,
sa.fontcolor as fontcolor_admin,
sa.label as label_admin,
count (case when cfiles.folder = '2' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '0' then 1 end ) count_bat_attente,
count (case when cfiles.folder = '1' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '0' then 1 end ) count_averifier,
count (case when cfiles.folder = '2' AND cfiles.bat_valid = '1' then 1 end) count_bat_valider,
SUM(nbr) as count_commandes,
count (case when cfmt.statut = '7' AND cfmt.hide = '0' then 1 end) count_modif_nohide,
count (case when cfmt.statut = '7' AND cfmt.hide IN (1) then 1 end) count_modif_hide

FROM projets as p INNER JOIN societe AS soc ON p.idsociete = soc.id
INNER JOIN statuts AS s ON p.idstatut = s.id
INNER JOIN statuts AS sa ON p.idstatut_admin = sa.id
left join files on files.idprojets=p.id
left join plans cplans on cplans.idprojets = p.id
left join files_modif_title cfmt on cfmt.idprojets = p.id
LEFT JOIN const AS cc ON cc.name = p.star AND cc.parent = 'star'
WHERE  p.idstatut IN (3)
AND p.deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.datecreate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "Here what I did, could it be better ?",...

Whereas your 9001 logic is valid, there is another problem...  `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is building a temp table of some number (1500?) of rows.  If you are running a version before 5.6, then these tmp tables have no index, and must be repeatedly scanned.  Now we are talking about 1500*1500*6 = millions of operations, not a mere 9001.

Even with 5.6, there is the extra step (6 times) to discover the optimal index and build it.

But, your real question is "how can I speed this up?".  The others have done a good job of answering that.